How to stop service's process when service has been stopped?
I have a startable service which is bound to separate process.
When service has been started a process is born.
But when service was stopped the process still alive and consuming RAM.
How to kill this process correctly?
Is it correct to call exitProcess(0) from a onDestoy method of the service?

"But when service was stopped the process still alive and consuming RAM" -- Android terminates processes as it sees fit. Your job is just to confirm that there are no bound clients to the service and that you stop the service. "How to kill this process correctly?" -- please leave it alone, just as you do with any other Android SDK process (e.g., the one with your UI).

It have to be killed in bounds of my goal.

There is no "correct" way for an app to kill one of its processes.

When your service is stopped, the process is moved to the "cached" list and the OS will reclaim that memory when needed. You do not need to (and should not try to) manage that lifecycle yourself. If your service is re-started later and the process is still in the cached list, the OS is able to efficiently re-use the existing process.

I have to kill it to calculate resource consumption, it's not a release just a stat capture service.
